# Plot a scatter plot with colour change spots in relation with a function

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I want to create a scatter plot in matlab and draw a 3D space with some points (x,y,z) but I want each point have its own colour in relation with an error function. For example, point A(0,2,1) with a small error (0.03) can have a light blue colour and a point B(-1,0,3) with an error 1.44 a dark blue colour. How can I print this colour change?

Comment: Including an example of code you've tried will greatly improve your chances of a helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`scatter3`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html):

```
x = randn(1,1000);
y = randn(1,1000);
z = randn(1,1000);
f = randn(1,1000); %// example data

scatter3(x,y,z,50,f,'.')
```

[image]

To customize the colormap, see [`colormap`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) function.